# Multiply each value in a vector to all values in a df in R

Tags: r, binary, dplyr

I have a df of binary variables as seen here:

```
df <- structure(list(Incident = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), WorkZone = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), Weather = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), SpecialEvents = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RecurringCongestion = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), MultipleCauses = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Unclassified = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I would like to take each value in the df of 10 and multiply each row by a correpsonding value in a vector, also size 10.

```
vect <- structure(list(UDC = c(102484.184937655, 126.379057607441, 132753.66551244, 
1042.40780236563, 2438.05671857084, 29124.7628066832, 6406.8910421133, 
141757.747682935, 95303.0160407684, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

So every entry in Row 1 of `df` is multplied by Row 1 in `vect`, and so on. However I get this error:

I try and do so below but I get this error

```
df <- df  %>%
  mutate_all(.,function(col){vect$UDC*col})



Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Incident`.
x Input `Incident` can't be recycled to size 1.
i Input `Incident` is `(function (col) ...`.
i Input `Incident` must be size 1, not 136.
i Did you mean: `Incident = list((function (col) ...)` ?
i The error occured in row 1.
```

Comment: `df * unlist(vect)` or even `df * vect[, 1]`

Comment: Damn, i overcomplicated that one haha

Answer (score 0):

There is a grouping attribute with `rowwise`, if we `ungroup`, it should work.  In `dplyr` 1.0.0, we can use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ . * vect$UDC))
```